Using replaykit or any other framework to capture whole screen and not just the app with script
I am trying to build an app that streams Iphone screen to PC over the wifi network. I am able to capture app's screen and receive it on my PC but if the app goes in background (I exit using home button), the stream still shows the app screen. I want to show it the current visible UI on Iphone.
This is the complete script.
import Foundation
import AVFoundation
import ReplayKit
import UIKit

class ScreenRecorder: NSObject, ObservableObject, StreamDelegate {
    private var recorder = RPScreenRecorder.shared()
    private var outputStream: OutputStream?
    private var backgroundTask: UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier = .invalid

    override init() {
        super.init()
    }

    func startCapturing() {
        setupStream()
        registerBackgroundTask()
        recorder.isMicrophoneEnabled = false
        recorder.startCapture(handler: { [weak self] (sampleBuffer, bufferType, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error capturing sample buffer: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }
            if bufferType == .video {
                self?.processSampleBuffer(sampleBuffer: sampleBuffer)
            }
        }) { error in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error starting capture: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            } else {
                print("Capture started successfully")
            }
        }
    }

    func stopCapturing() {
        recorder.stopCapture { [weak self] error in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error stopping capture: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
            self?.outputStream?.close()
            self?.outputStream = nil
        }
        endBackgroundTask()
    }

    private func processSampleBuffer(sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer) {
        guard let outputStream = outputStream else {
            print("Output stream is nil")
            return
        }

        guard CMSampleBufferDataIsReady(sampleBuffer) else {
            print("Sample buffer data is not ready")
            return
        }

        if let imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer) {
        
            let ciImage = CIImage(cvImageBuffer: imageBuffer)
            let context = CIContext()
            
        
            if let jpegData = context.jpegRepresentation(of: ciImage, colorSpace: CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(), options: [:]) {
                var frameSize = UInt32(jpegData.count)
                var sizeData = Data(bytes: &frameSize, count: MemoryLayout<UInt32>.size)
                
                // Send the frame size
                sizeData.withUnsafeBytes { (rawBufferPointer: UnsafeRawBufferPointer) in
                    if let baseAddress = rawBufferPointer.baseAddress {
                        let bytesWritten = outputStream.write(baseAddress.assumingMemoryBound(to: UInt8.self), maxLength: sizeData.count)
                        if bytesWritten <= 0 {
                            print("Error writing frame size to output stream: \(outputStream.streamError?.localizedDescription ?? "Unknown error")")
                            return
                        } else {
                            print("Wrote frame size \(frameSize) to output stream")
                        }
                    }
                }
                
            
                jpegData.withUnsafeBytes { (rawBufferPointer: UnsafeRawBufferPointer) in
                    if let baseAddress = rawBufferPointer.baseAddress {
                        let bytesWritten = outputStream.write(baseAddress.assumingMemoryBound(to: UInt8.self), maxLength: jpegData.count)
                        if bytesWritten <= 0 {
                            print("Error writing frame data to output stream: \(outputStream.streamError?.localizedDescription ?? "Unknown error")")
                        } else {
                            print("Wrote \(bytesWritten) bytes of sample buffer data to the output stream")
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                print("Error converting CIImage to JPEG data")
            }
        } else {
            print("Failed to get image buffer")
        }
    }


    func setupStream() {
        var readStream: Unmanaged<CFReadStream>?
        var writeStream: Unmanaged<CFWriteStream>?

        let ipAddress = "192.168.x.xx" 
        let port: UInt32 = 5001
        print("Attempting to connect to \(ipAddress) on port \(port)")

        CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(kCFAllocatorDefault, ipAddress as CFString, port, &readStream, &writeStream)

        guard let outStream = writeStream?.takeRetainedValue() else {
            print("Failed to create write stream")
            return
        }
        outputStream = outStream
        outputStream?.delegate = self
        outputStream?.schedule(in: .current, forMode: .default)
        outputStream?.open()

        print("Stream setup complete, attempting to open output stream")
    }

    func stream(_ aStream: Stream, handle eventCode: Stream.Event) {
        switch eventCode {
        case .openCompleted:
            print("Stream opened successfully")
        case .hasBytesAvailable:
            print("Stream has bytes available")
        case .hasSpaceAvailable:
            print("Stream has space available")
        case .errorOccurred:
            if let error = aStream.streamError {
                print("Stream error occurred: \(error)")
            }
        case .endEncountered:
            print("Stream end encountered")
            aStream.close()
            aStream.remove(from: .current, forMode: .default)
        default:
            print("Unknown stream event")
        }
    }

    private func registerBackgroundTask() {
        backgroundTask = UIApplication.shared.beginBackgroundTask { [weak self] in
            self?.endBackgroundTask()
        }
        assert(backgroundTask != .invalid)
    }

    private func endBackgroundTask() {
        if backgroundTask != .invalid {
            UIApplication.shared.endBackgroundTask(backgroundTask)
            backgroundTask = .invalid
        }
    }
}



It only shows this much on my mac screen. Please help!. I am not able to figure out a way to stream my complete screen. Is it possible?
iOS version - 18
Xcode version - 16
Macos version - sequoia 15
Edit:
I tried using RPBroadcastHandler as suggested in comment so I,

Added New target in my App (Broadcast upload extension) and got a new target scaffolded in my App.
This is what the project structure looks like now.

The updated SampleHandler.swift looks like this

import ReplayKit
import VideoToolbox

class SampleHandler: RPBroadcastSampleHandler {
    var outputStream: OutputStream?

    override func broadcastStarted(withSetupInfo setupInfo: [String : NSObject]?) {
        setupStream()
    }
    
    override func broadcastPaused() { }
    
    override func broadcastResumed() { }
    
    override func broadcastFinished() {
        outputStream?.close()
    }
    
    func setupStream() {
        var writeStream: Unmanaged<CFWriteStream>?
        let ipAddress = "192.168.1.38"
        let port: UInt32 = 5000
        
        CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(kCFAllocatorDefault, ipAddress as CFString, port, nil, &writeStream)
        
        outputStream = writeStream?.takeRetainedValue()
        outputStream?.schedule(in: .current, forMode: .default)
        outputStream?.open()
    }
    
    override func processSampleBuffer(_ sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, with sampleBufferType: RPSampleBufferType) {
        guard let outputStream = outputStream, sampleBufferType == .video else { return }
        
        guard let imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer) else { return }
        let ciImage = CIImage(cvImageBuffer: imageBuffer)
        let context = CIContext()
        
        if let jpegData = context.jpegRepresentation(of: ciImage, colorSpace: CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(), options: [:]) {
            let _ = jpegData.withUnsafeBytes { outputStream.write($0.bindMemory(to: UInt8.self).baseAddress!, maxLength: jpegData.count) }
        }
    }
}


I left the other files unchanged and "Build and Run".
Xcode prompts me to select an app to run, I choose "ScreenStreamer" As it is what includes the extension.
Once the app is installed, it shows this dialog.

Error details -

The specified capability is not supported by this device.
Domain: com.apple.dt.CoreDeviceError
Code: 1001
User Info: {
    DVTErrorCreationDateKey = "2024-08-02 12:18:47 +0000";
    IDERunOperationFailingWorker = IDEDebugXPCCoreDeviceWorker;
    ServiceName = "com.apple.instruments.dtservicehub";
}
--

Event Metadata: com.apple.dt.IDERunOperationWorkerFinished : {
    "device_identifier" = "00008020-000848683A84002E";
    "device_isCoreDevice" = 1;
    "device_model" = "iPhone11,6";
    "device_osBuild" = "18.0 (22A5316j)";
    "device_platform" = "com.apple.platform.iphoneos";
    "device_thinningType" = "iPhone11,6";
    "dvt_coredevice_version" = "397.16";
    "dvt_coresimulator_version" = 986;
    "dvt_mobiledevice_version" = "1759.0.5";
    "launchSession_schemeCommand" = Run;
    "launchSession_state" = 1;
    "launchSession_targetArch" = arm64;
    "operation_duration_ms" = 3252;
    "operation_errorCode" = 1001;
    "operation_errorDomain" = "com.apple.dt.CoreDeviceError";
    "operation_errorWorker" = IDEDebugXPCCoreDeviceWorker;
    "operation_name" = IDERunOperationWorkerGroup;
    "param_debugger_attachToExtensions" = 1;
    "param_debugger_attachToXPC" = 1;
    "param_debugger_type" = 1;
    "param_destination_isProxy" = 0;
    "param_destination_platform" = "com.apple.platform.iphoneos";
    "param_diag_113575882_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_MainThreadChecker_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_MallocStackLogging_enableDuringAttach" = 0;
    "param_diag_MallocStackLogging_enableForXPC" = 1;
    "param_diag_allowLocationSimulation" = 1;
    "param_diag_checker_tpc_enable" = 1;
    "param_diag_gpu_frameCapture_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_gpu_shaderValidation_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_gpu_validation_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_memoryGraphOnResourceException" = 0;
    "param_diag_mtc_enable" = 1;
    "param_diag_queueDebugging_enable" = 1;
    "param_diag_runtimeProfile_generate" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_asan_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_tsan_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_tsan_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_ubsan_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_ubsan_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_showNonLocalizedStrings" = 0;
    "param_diag_viewDebugging_enabled" = 1;
    "param_diag_viewDebugging_insertDylibOnLaunch" = 1;
    "param_install_style" = 2;
    "param_launcher_UID" = 2;
    "param_launcher_allowDeviceSensorReplayData" = 0;
    "param_launcher_kind" = 0;
    "param_launcher_style" = 0;
    "param_launcher_substyle" = 2;
    "param_runnable_appExtensionHostRunMode" = 0;
    "param_runnable_productType" = "com.apple.product-type.app-extension";
    "param_structuredConsoleMode" = 1;
    "param_testing_launchedForTesting" = 0;
    "param_testing_suppressSimulatorApp" = 0;
    "param_testing_usingCLI" = 0;
    "sdk_canonicalName" = "iphoneos18.0";
    "sdk_osVersion" = "18.0";
    "sdk_variant" = iphoneos;
}
--


System Information

macOS Version 15.0 (Build 24A5298h)
Xcode 16.0 (23047) (Build 16A5211f)
Timestamp: 2024-08-02T17:48:47+05:30

I am not sure what is causing this error.

Thank you @iSpain17 @GoksuBayy for suggestions. Here's what worked for me.
I set up the broadcast extension like usual and created a picker button to launch the Broadcast Extension picker.
ViewController.swift
import UIKit
import ReplayKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.addSubview(pickerButton)
        pickerButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            pickerButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            pickerButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),
            pickerButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 44),
            pickerButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 44)
        ])
        view.bringSubviewToFront(pickerButton)
    }
    let pickerButton: RPSystemBroadcastPickerView = {
        let picker = RPSystemBroadcastPickerView(frame: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: 44, height: 44)))
        picker.preferredExtension = "com.MH.screen-sharing-example.screen-share-extension"
        return picker
    }()
   
}

Then for processing Video buffer, this implementation worked for me.
SampleHandler.swift
//
//  SampleHandler.swift
//  screen-share-extension
//
//  Created by Prayas Gautam on 05/08/24.
//

import UIKit
import ReplayKit
import Network
import Foundation


class SampleHandler: RPBroadcastSampleHandler {
    
    var connection: NWConnection?
    var lastSendTime: TimeInterval = 0
    let sendInterval: TimeInterval = 1.0 / 10.0 // 30 FPS

    override init() {
        super.init()
        setupConnection()
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(appDidEnterBackground), name: UIApplication.didEnterBackgroundNotification, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(appWillEnterForeground), name: UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification, object: nil)
    }
    
    deinit {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
    }
    
    func setupConnection() {
        let host = NWEndpoint.Host("192.168.x.xx")
        let port = NWEndpoint.Port(integerLiteral: 8080)
        connection = NWConnection(host: host, port: port, using: .udp)
        connection?.start(queue: .main)
    }
    
    func processVideoSampleBuffer(_ sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer) {
        guard let connection = connection else { return }
               
               // Convert sample buffer to data
       guard let imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer) else { return }
       let ciImage = CIImage(cvImageBuffer: imageBuffer)
       let context = CIContext()
       guard let cgImage = context.createCGImage(ciImage, from: ciImage.extent) else { return }
       
       // Resize the image
       let uiImage = UIImage(cgImage: cgImage)
       let size = CGSize(width: uiImage.size.width / 2, height: uiImage.size.height / 2) // Reduce resolution by half
       UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size)
       uiImage.draw(in: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size))
       let resizedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
       UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
       
       guard let jpegData = resizedImage?.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.2) else { return } // Adjust compression quality
       
       // Send data over UDP
       connection.send(content: jpegData, completion: .contentProcessed({ sendError in
           if let sendError = sendError {
               NSLog("Failed to send data: \(sendError)")
           } else {
               NSLog("Data sent successfully")
           }
       }))
    }
    
    @objc func appDidEnterBackground() {
        // Pause streaming or reduce frequency
        NSLog("App entered background")
    }
    
    @objc func appWillEnterForeground() {
        // Resume streaming
        NSLog("App will enter foreground")
    }
    override func broadcastStarted(withSetupInfo setupInfo: [String : NSObject]?) {
        // User has requested to start the broadcast. Setup info from the UI extension can be supplied but optional. 
    }
    
    override func broadcastPaused() {
        // User has requested to pause the broadcast. Samples will stop being delivered.
    }
    
    override func broadcastResumed() {
        // User has requested to resume the broadcast. Samples delivery will resume.
    }
    
    override func broadcastFinished() {
        // User has requested to finish the broadcast.
    }
    
    override func processSampleBuffer(_ sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, with sampleBufferType: RPSampleBufferType) {
        switch sampleBufferType {
        case RPSampleBufferType.video:
            let currentTime = CACurrentMediaTime()
            if currentTime - lastSendTime >= sendInterval {
                lastSendTime = currentTime
                processVideoSampleBuffer(sampleBuffer)
            }
            break
        case RPSampleBufferType.audioApp:
            // Handle audio sample buffer for app audio
            break
        case RPSampleBufferType.audioMic:
            // Handle audio sample buffer for mic audio
            break
        @unknown default:
            // Handle other sample buffer types
            fatalError("Unknown type of sample buffer")
        }
    }
}


Python script to receive the stream on PC.
import socket
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Set up socket
UDP_IP = "0.0.0.0"
UDP_PORT = 8080
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.bind((UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))

while True:
    data, addr = sock.recvfrom(65536)  

    np_data = np.frombuffer(data, dtype=np.uint8)
    frame = cv2.imdecode(np_data, 1)
    
    if frame is not None:
        cv2.imshow('Video Stream', frame)
        
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break

# Release resources
sock.close()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()



It is not possible I guess, Apple RPSCreenRecorder documentation says "Your app can record the audio and video inside of the app" so you can not record iPhone screen except for your app screen. However you can use RPBroadcastSampleHandler to stream your iPhone. see: RPBroadcastSampleHandler

Thank you for the response, does "RPBroadcastSampleHandler" allow to stream complete UI screen? I am okay with not being able to record the screen as long as i can receive a stream of iphone on my pc.

Yes, you receive CMSampleBuffers of the entire screen. Create a "Broadcast Upload Extension" in Xcode and you get a basic scaffolded broadcast extension. Bonus Tip: as long as you stay in the extension, you can use VideoToolBox to encode your video samples with the GPU. Broadcast extensions are rather limited in RAM usage - last I checked the allowed RAM was 50MB so you must deallocate samples as quickly as possible.

Thank you, I'll try to implement and update here.

@iSpain17 I tried it with my iphone xs max (ios 18) but xcode (version 16) throws an error saying this capability is not supported on this device. Is this due to beta version or just the hardware limitation?

We need code to understand why that error is thrown.

@iSpain17 Here's my SampleHandler.swift code, i didn't change anything else in scaffolded extension code.
https://gist.github.com/Imprayas12/524d1b62ef2296eed80ecfeb0166d40d

What throws the error? Do you have the Broadcast Setup UI Extension set up correctly as well? What capability? Can you update your question with as many details as possible? (All code, exception stack trace, where the exception is thrown and when, etc.)

@iSpain17 I've updated the question description with all the details.

@PrayasGautam Have you checked "Required device capabilities" in Info.plist ?  Maybe something is missing there

@GoksuBayy Info.plist didn't include "Required Device capabilities" key, which key-value should be there in order for this to work? I looked up the docs but it didn't specify the required values.

@iSpain17  Thank you for the advice. I got the broadcast working and i am able to view it on my mac. I'm facing one issue, the video starts lagging as soon as i put the app in background and comes active again when i put the app in foreground. Could it be due to RAM issue.

"ReplayKit provides sample buffers sequentially. After invoking this method with a sample buffer, ReplayKit won’t invoke the method again for any sample buffer type until the current invocation returns." Your processSampleBuffer method copies between buffers, produces a jpeg image and etc. - those are expensive operations to perform on the CPU. In background, you also only have access to efficiency cores. I would look at how to make my processSampleBuffer function faster to run. Profile it, try to offload work to GPU (VideoToolbox) or use tried and tested CPU methods (vImage)

Also I don't think you need all that conversion from CVPixelBuffer to JPEG to bytes. Why not just transmit the bytes of the CVPixelBuffer directly?

@iSpain17 I'm sorry I am not able to optimize it further, can you please review it once and tell me? If possible can you let me know the changes needed in this function? I'll be grateful. Right now it's a little better but not good enough that can be used:  https://gist.github.com/Imprayas12/0f020e86c3a5727dfbde938ccc60a7b5
